# How to wrap a DOM element object in a custom class

Tags: javascript, dom, javascript-objects

I have a class called `ScrollContainer` which is constructed with an optional selector string parameter such as `new ScrollContainer('#my-element');`.

If no selector is provided, `window` is used as default.

I want to have a method called `getDistanceFromTop()` which will have some logic depending if the container is an element or `window`.

All of that works fine so far, but when I want to use native methods such as `scrollTo()` I need to create a wrapper for that method even though both elements and `window` have the same interface for that.

My idea was then to make this `ScrollContainer` inherit something like `Element`, but then I don't know how I would be able to initialize this element. I'm thinking something like `super('#my-element')` or `super(document.querySelector('#my-element')`.

Is it possible to create this wrapper in the way I want? Is this line of thinking correct?

All answers I've found said something about not extending DOM elements, but I'm pretty sure the use cases were quite different from mine.

I don't want to create a custom element to be used in the DOM, or to add methods directly to `Element` prototype, I just want to have a wrapper to be able to use some isolated helper functions while still being able to call the base methods without having to wrap them all.

More info:

```js
export class ScrollContainer {
  constructor(containerSelector) {
    let container = window;

    if (containerSelector) {
      container = document.querySelector(this.scrollContainerSelector) || window;
    }

    this.container = container;
  }

  addScrollListener(callback) {
    this.scrollListenerCallback = callback;
    this.container.addEventListener('scroll', callback);
  }

  removeScrollListener() {
    this.container.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollListenerCallback);
  }

  getDistanceFromTop() {
    return this.container.scrollTop || this.container.pageYOffset;
  }

  scrollTo(x, y) {
    return this.container.scrollTo(x, y);
  }

  getOffsetTop() {
    return this.container.offsetTop;
  }
}
```

This is the class I currently have. It works perfectly, the only thing that bothers me is those unnecessary wrappers such as `scrollTo()` and `getOffsetTop()` methods which don't have anything special, they just call the native method.

Comment: Since the OP facades a dom element, it is perfectly fine to duplicate the functionality that is needed from the wrapped element and implement it in the shown forwarding way.

Comment: ... just noticed it ... shouldn't it be `if (containerSelector) { container = document.querySelector(containerSelector) || window; }` with the first 6 lines of code even shortened to `this.container = (containerSelector && document.querySelector(containerSelector)) || window;`

Comment: @PeterSeliger I know it's fine to do that but it looks ugly and not scalable. I want this class to be treated as an Element, but I don't want to implement every single method I need from it, I just want the calls to be delegated using inheritance. About your second comment yes, it can be shortened but I usually prefer simpler and more readable code, just a matter of preference I guess

Comment: All right then ... in an ideal world [_**Web Components**_](https://www.webcomponents.org/specs#the-custom-elements-specification) was the tool of your choice. But if you can [narrow the base of the targeted clients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components#Browser_compatibility) the MDN tutorial of [*Using Custom Elements*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#High-level_view) might be likewise interesting to you.

Comment: That seems like too much overhead for such a simple problem. As I've said I don't need to create a custom element to be used in the DOM, it's just a facade to add some utility to an object. I wasn't able to find any resource on that so I'm guessing this is probably harder than it should be for some reason, I just wanted to know the reasons so that I can know its background better. As I've said this should be as simple as calling super() in this class constructor while extending Element, but looks like it's not. Thanks for the help anyway